# Git detect logical duplicate files and fail merge

Tags: git, github

Is there a mechanism in `git`, or `GitHub`, that can detect the file `007__JamesBond.txt` has been created on the master branch by Alice and that Bob has created `007__TheSpyWho.txt` on a feature branch?

When Bob comes to merge his branch with master, the merge should be marked as conflicted because of the duplicate logical prefix “007” when ignoring everything after the first double-underscore.

It would ideally behave as if both people committed `007.txt`, which would naturally flag up a merge conflict.

The filter should only be applied to selected directories. Both files can be expected to be in the same directory so we don’t need to scan very widely to find duplicates.

The real-world application is a set of files used by the Flyway database library to maintain DDL scripts. The library expects a description in the filename after the unique number.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a **githook** could solve this.  You would have to write your own script, but once that's working git will just go through the hook. [Here's the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing; I was going down a blind alley thinking about merging and potentially “custom merge drivers”. In fact, it’s not really related to the merge and is instead a validation of the state of a repository. I’ll look into a commit hook and post the answer as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script installed as `.git/hooks/commit-msg` successfully detects logical duplicates when running `git commit` and `git merge`. Configuring it as the `pre-commit` hook doesn't work for merges, only for commits, so better to mount it as `commit-msg`.

```
#!/bin/bash

##################################################################
# Detect flyway logical duplicates with the same numbered prefix #
##################################################################

#Place each directory to check on a new line without any commas
flywaydirs=(
  "mycomponent1/src/main/resources/db"
  "mycomponent1/src/main/resources/db"
)

#The prefix and the main name of the file are separated by __ so we'll see files like:
#V1_prefix__main_name.sql

duplicateprefixes=()
for i in "${flywaydirs[@]}"
do
  while read -r line
  do
    duplicateprefixes+=($line)
  #Ignore filenames prefixed with R__
  done < <(git ls-files $i | sort | grep -v '/R__' | sed 's/__[^__].*$//g' | uniq -d)
done

if [ ${#duplicateprefixes[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Found duplicate flyway files:"
  for i in "${duplicateprefixes[@]}"
  do
    git ls-files ${i}__*
  done
  echo "## Aborting commit ##"
  exit 3
else
  echo "No duplicate flyway files detected. Test passed."
fi
```